# Test with Moq if a method of external library is called

Tags: c#, unit-testing, moq

For a project I'm using the CompositeContainer class of the MEF framework. Now I'd like to make a unit test (with moq) that verifies if the ComposeParts (which is an extension method in AttributedModelServices) method is called.

Just mocking it with moq doesn't work because the method is not virtual. I found some ways to do this but all of them makes me change the CompositeContainer class, which I cannot do.

Is there a way in moq to test if a non virtual method of an external 3rd party library is called?

Thanks in advance for your reply.

example code:

```
public void Load(string path, CompositionContainer container)
{           
    container.ComposeParts(this);           
}
```

Here container is from the MEF library and ComposeParts an extension method in the  System.ComponentModel.Composition namespace:

```
//
// Summary:
//     Creates composable parts from an array of attributed objects and composes
//     them in the specified composition container.
//
// Parameters:
//   container:
//     The composition container to perform composition in.
//
//   attributedParts:
//     An array of attributed objects to compose.
public static void ComposeParts(this CompositionContainer container, params object[] attributedParts);
```

Comment: Can you show an example of the extension method you are calling?

Comment: You try to test if a class, which is not from you, calls a method?

Comment: Perhaps you are testing the wrong piece of code, maybe you should test the effects of calling this method on your application.

Comment: I added an example, and what I want to test if simply if the load method calls the ComposeParts method of the CompositionContainer. It is exactly the same as with mocking interfaces but now with a concrete class from an external library.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't believe that it's possible to verify directly that a third party library method was called with Moq, but you can check the side effects of calling the method. Since you are using MEF to retrieve your implementations at runtime I would test that your types were loaded correctly. So if you have something like this:

```
public interface IInterfaceToCompose
{
    string MethodToCreate();
}

[Export(typeof(IInterfaceToCompose))]
public class ConcreteImplementation1 : IInterfaceToCompose
{
    public string MethodToCreate()
    {
        return "Implementation 1";
    }
}

[Export(typeof(IInterfaceToCompose))]
public class ConcreteImplementation2 : IInterfaceToCompose
{
    public string MethodToCreate()
    {
        return "Implementation 2";
    }
}
```

You could then write a test that looks something like this:

```
[ImportMany(typeof(IInterfaceToCompose))]
public IInterfaceToCompose ComposedItems { get; set; }

[Test]
public void WhenComposingTheComposedItems_ShouldLoadExportedTypes()
{
    Load("testPath", YourContainer);

    Assert.AreEqual(2, ComposedItems.Count());
}
```

What you really want to test (IMO) is that you created your composed classes correctly and that they can all be loaded by the MEF CompositionContainer.

A good second test would be to do an initial load, add a dll with a third implementer, and ensure that the final count is 3 (does your system dynamically load new modules). This will catch errors such as forgetting to attribute the new implementations with the Export attribute and also make sure that your classes are correctly picking up changes as they occur.

Comment: I could indeed use the function and see if it load modules. But then I'm technically also testing third party code. I was wondering if i could to that without it. The only thing i need to know here is: "does it call the method". If that method works or not is another unit test (and someone else's concern).

Comment: Next best thing that I can think of would be to make a wrapper interface ICompositionContainer with a method called ComposedParts and you can send a mock for the test and a wrapped version of the real thing in production/integration test scenario. Then you can assert that the interface method was called. While this won't prove that your wrapper class is correct it would prove that an object that takes an interface of type ICompositionContainer has the ComposeParts method called (which sounds like what you would like anyway).

Comment: I was hoping that I could skip the setup of a dummy module to test the method, but it seems to be the only way. Creating a wrapper and interface just moves the problem to the wrapper and adds unnecessary code to the tested class. So I go for this answer. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

It the Load method implemented in your class? Did you consider removing it from there? Taking into account the single responsibility principle, it looks like your class does too much.

I would suggest, that you split the functionality - your class does whatever business logic it needs to do. And have another "infrastructure" class which is responsible to compose the container - in your case to get an instance of your class, and register it in the container.

You will have almost the same problem, but in another place. And this "new" place will be much more focused about its functionality, and you can test it in isolation, using a real container, and examine it if the right parts were composed.

Comment: that's exactly the actual class you're describing, but since i wanted to give a simple example, I gave this code, to keep things clear.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to just check that a method is called you can wrap the CompositionContainer in a wrapper interface called ICompositionContainer that has the same method signatures. Then with Moq you could assert that the method was called:

```
mock.Verify(cc => cc.ComposeParts(), Times.Once());
```

The negative here is that you are creating an interface to hide the fact that the original implementation did not implement one for you.

The example code would now be :

```
public void Load(string path, ICompositionContainer container)
{           
    container.ComposeParts(this);           
}
```

There are examples of other projects that wrap problematic to test classes in the .NET framework such as [SystemWrapper](http://systemwrapper.codeplex.com/).